# Can elbow fitting be used to line up drain tailpiece with trap

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, plumbing-fixture, p-trap

I installed a new vanity and the drain tailpipe does not line up with the P trap. Can I use two 90 degree elbow fittings to make this connect? Can elbows connect to elbows directly or does it require an extender in the middle? See the picture of my problem. [image]

Comment: Putting a sharp bend at the bottom of the tailpiece is asking for trouble.

Comment: Can you post a picture from the front showing the left-to-right offset between the drain and the wall connection?

Comment: Can you take a picture of the pipe going into the wall (to the left of the current pic)? Most of the sinks I've seen have a sliding section with a compression fit, just like the one that comes straight down from the sink. This makes it so you can move the trap under the drain (nearly) regardless which sink you use.

Answer (score 11):

The best repair for this problem is to cut the trap from the drain pipe, glue on an ABS 1 1/2 inch (or same pipe diameter as existing pipe) coupling and than a short section of new pipe long enough to bring the trap under the sink tail piece.

You wll have a little bit of leeway because the trap section can pivot from the threaded connection.

Comment: I have the same problem with a new laundry tub that has a different drain location the previous tub....but I don't understand your solution.  can you elaborate?